# Elastic Search Function_Score Query with Query_String

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I was doing search using elastic search using the code:

```
es.search(index="article-index", fields="url", body={
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "keywordstr",
      "fields": [
        "text",
        "title",
        "tags",
        "domain"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Now I want to insert another parameter in the search scoring - "recencyboost".

I was told function_score should solve the problem

```
res = es.search(index="article-index", fields="url", body={
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": {
        "DECAY_FUNCTION": {
          "recencyboost": {
            "origin": "0",
            "scale": "20"
          }
        }
      },
      "query": {
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": keywordstr
          }
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
})
```

It gives me error that dictionary `{"query_string": {"query": keywordstr}}` is not hashable.

1) How can I fix the error?

2) How can I change the decay function such that it give higher weight to higher recency boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have an extra `query` in your search (giving a total of three), which is giving you an unwanted top-level.  You need to remove the top-level `query` and replace it with [`function_score`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) as the top level key.

```
res = es.search(index="article-index", fields="url", body={"function_score": {
    "query": {
        { "query_string": {"query": keywordstr} }
    },
    "functions": {
        "DECAY_FUNCTION": {
            "recencyboost": {
                "origin": "0",
                "scale": "20"
            }
        }
    },
    "score_mode": "multiply"
})
```

Note: `score_mode` defaults to `"multiply"`, as does the unused `boost_mode`, so it should be unnecessary to supply it.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use dictionary as a key in the dictionary. You are doing this in the following segment of the code:

```
"query": {
    {"query_string": {"query": keywordstr}}
},
```

Following should work fine

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {"query": keywordstr}
},
```

Answer (score -1):

use it like this

```
     query: {
        function_score: {
          query: {
            filtered: {
              query: {
                bool: {
                   must: [
                      {
                        query_string: {
                          query: shop_search,
                          fields: [ 'shop_name']
                        },
                        boost: 2.0
                      },
                      {
                        query_string: {
                          query: shop_search,
                          fields: [ 'shop_name']
                        },
                        boost: 3.0
                      }
                  ]
                }
            },
            filter: {
      //          { term: { search_city:  }}
            }
          },
          exp: {
            location: {  
               origin: { lat:  12.8748964,
                lon: 77.6413239
              },
              scale: "10000m",
              offset: "0m",
              decay: "0.5"
            }
          }
  //        score_mode: "sum"
        }
```